# SQL: Update table using JOIN clause

Tags: sql, sql-update, rdbms, sql-execution-plan

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the query below to update a very large table (5 million records) using batches of 50.000 coming from an import table:

```
set rowcount 50000
update c
set         
     AddressLine1 = d.AddressLine1      
    ,Postcode = d.Postcode
    ,FirstName = d.FORENAME
    ,LastName = d.SURNAME
    ,TelephoneNumber = d.TelephoneNumber
    ,EmailAddress = d.EMAIL_ADDRESS
    ,DataExpiryDate = getdate()
    ,DateCreated = getdate()        
    ,DateModified = getdate()   
FROM 
Customer c
inner join 
[Import_Table] d        
on  
c.AccountNumber = d.AccountNumber 
AND 
c.Id = d.Id
where 
c.DateModified < '2016-01-25 12:00:00 AM' 
set rowcount 0
```

Each batch takes aproximately 9 minutes.

Is there any way to improve the query above?

I added unique indexes for: (AccountNumber, Id) and (Id, AccountNumber).

Update: I have added the old plan (before including the DateModified column in the index) and also the new one (see below).

Thanks,
A

[Initial query plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl580.png)

[New Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XCau.png)

Comment: Are you using SQL server, or another RDBMS? I would make (Id, AccountNumber) your primary key rather than a unique index on `d`.

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan? You'll also want to monitor to see where the bottleneck is. No one here is going to know your hardware setup, so whether the problem is that your disk IO bound or have memory issues is something that we won't be able to tell.

Comment: Tag dbms used! (Update-join is product specific...)

Comment: Hi,
I am using SQL Server 2014.
I looked at the query plan and the most expensive part is "Compute Scalar" (74%). I can't attach the image as I don't have enough rights :D
I also have an index seek (2%) on Customer (AccountNumber, SiteId) and a Clustered Index Scan (13%) on Import_Table (Icoms_Account_Uid - this is the primary key).

Comment: 1) Remove one of the indexes, you don't need both. 2) Add DateModified as an INCLUDE field to your indexes. Check that this index exists on both tables. 3) Don't be confused about the percentage in the query plan, it means only what SQL Server expect. However reality often is different from expectation. 4) Query plan will be useful to see.

Comment: Thanks, I added the index on both tables and now the query runs in less than 6 minutes for 50k rows. One other drawback might be the fact that I am running the query in AWS. I will try to run it on a PC that has better configuration.

Comment: Hi Denis,
Can you post your comment again as Answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

Dump the GETDATE() function; it's being performed for every single update.  Do it once and pass in the value.

```
DECLARE @updateDT DATETIME

SET @updateDT=GETDATE()

set rowcount 50000
update c
set         
     AddressLine1 = d.AddressLine1      
    ,Postcode = d.Postcode
    ,FirstName = d.FORENAME
    ,LastName = d.SURNAME
    ,TelephoneNumber = d.TelephoneNumber
    ,EmailAddress = d.EMAIL_ADDRESS
    ,DataExpiryDate = @updateDT
    ,DateCreated = @updateDT        
    ,DateModified = @updateDT   
FROM 
Customer c
inner join 
[Import_Table] d        
on  
c.AccountNumber = d.AccountNumber 
AND 
c.Id = d.Id
where 
c.DateModified < '2016-01-25 12:00:00 AM' 
set rowcount 0
```